# GitLab Ci enviroment variables. Tests working local but not in the pipeline

Tags: php, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I am facing a problem in the gitlab-ci. This is my gitlab-ci.yml. My local tests are fine. So I am executing codecept in the container and tests are running good. But in the pipeline it fails.

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - apk update
  - apk upgrade
  - apk add python3 python3-dev py-pip build-base libffi-dev openssl-dev
  - pip install docker-compose

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker exec -i -e MYSQL_HOST=beerfridgeaccountingwebsite_claudia-app-db_1 -e MYSQL_DB=bierkasse_test -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_PWD=rootPassword1 beerfridgeaccountingwebsite_claudia-app-php_1 /bin/sh  -c "export && composer install && ./vendor/bin/codecept run functional"
```

Do I have to push env variables in there like this? Thought the host is the tagged container with the mysql db in it. Like its local. And the export is showing the right values so env vars should be inside there?

This is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  claudia-app-nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - claudia-app-php

  claudia-app-php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - claudia-app-db

  claudia-app-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    entrypoint:
      sh -c "
      echo 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bierkasse; CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bierkasse_test;' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;
      /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
```

This is my test. Do I also need to use a env. var here instead of using strings with the needed data?

```
  public function testConnectionIsReturningProperly()
    {
        $connection = new Connection();
        $connection->connect("beerfridgeaccountingwebsite_claudia-app-db_1", "bierkasse_test", "root", "rootPassword1");

    }
```

And this is the connect() function used in code. Local its loading variables from .env file.

```
$pdo =  (new ConnectionDB)->connect($_SERVER['MYSQL_HOST'], $_SERVER['MYSQL_DB'], $_SERVER['MYSQL_USER'], $_SERVER['MYSQL_PWD']);
```

This is the error in codeception in the pipeline:

```
  Db: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Na  
   me does not resolve while creating PDO connection
```

Thanks in advance for any little hint.

Comment: the db host you're passing to the test is unknown, you should maybe try 127.0.0.1 instead (in pipeline context where docker compose just run your db as docker container)

Comment: I solved it. The host was unknown because I forgot do declare rootPassword in the enviroment of docker-compose file. And I red this is mandatory for mysql container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docker compose file there need to be a rootPassword under enviroment of the mysql container.
Here is the discription in docker hub:
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
This variable is mandatory and specifies the password that will be set for the MySQL root superuser account. In the above example, it was set to my-secret-pw.
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql